# how to display size attribute of simple product in bundle product

Tags: magento, size, bundle

I created bundle products it displays name + price of products, however i want to display size of simple products not name and price. How can i enable Magento to display size attribute on simple products? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Step1:- Find below file in your theme.

app\design\frontend{{your theme}}\default\template\bundle\catalog\product\view\type\bundle\option/select.phtml

Step2:-

Please find below code in above file

```
<?php foreach ($_selections as $_selection): ?>
            <?php if ($_selection->getSelectionCanChangeQty() && $this->_isSelected($_selection)): ?>
                <?php $tierPriceHtml = $this->getTierPriceHtml($_selection); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $_selection->getSelectionId() ?>"<?php if ($this->_isSelected($_selection)) echo ' selected="selected"' ?><?php if (!$_selection->isSaleable()) echo ' disabled="disabled"' ?>><?php echo $this->getSelectionTitlePrice($_selection, false) ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Replace with this code

```
<?php foreach ($_selections as $_selection): ?>
            **<?php $productLoad=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_selection->getId()); ?>**
            <?php if ($_selection->getSelectionCanChangeQty() && $this->_isSelected($_selection)): ?>
                <?php $tierPriceHtml = $this->getTierPriceHtml($_selection); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $_selection->getSelectionId() ?>"<?php if ($this->_isSelected($_selection)) echo ' selected="selected"' ?><?php if (!$_selection->isSaleable()) echo ' disabled="disabled"' ?>><?php echo $productLoad->getAttributeText('size'); ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```